# Detect file drag & drop to the right/left of the desktop

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, screen

For a small demonstration application, I want the option to delete file (from the files explorer on windows) by simple dragging it all the way to left/right side of the screen (the all desktop, not the application)
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For demonstration purposes you could create a borderless always on top window that fills the entire screen and cut out a hole in the middle of it with a window region so you are left with just a 1 or 2 pixel wide strip on each side and set the opacity to 1 so it is basically invisible. You could then handle drops on the window.

On Windows 8 you might run into issues because it already uses the edges.

I don't believe this feature is useful enough to actually implement as a real product though.